# Variable doesn't get updated correctly, seems like one line of code gets run every time

Tags: python, python-3.x

My first line of code sets h to None. Then when I enter the for loop for the 1st time, h gets updated in the merge_to_hierarchy method. However on the 2nd time when I'm in the loop, my h has been set to None again. How do I update my h variable correctly or make sure that my 1st line of code only gets run once?

```
h = get_hierarchy((script_data.data_version, script_data.elt_type_data[0]))

for fle in glob.glob('./' + script_data.folder_with_csvs + '/*'):
    [region, peril, subregion] = (re.sub('.csv', '', (re.sub('./' + script_data.folder_with_csvs + '/', '', fle)))).split("_")
    h = merge_to_hierarchy(h, peril, region, subregion)
    print(h)
    change_file(str(fle))

def change_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        next(r)

def merge_to_hierarchy(h, peril, region, subregion):
    if h is None:
        h = Hierarchy(script_data.data_version, script_data.elt_type_data[0], [
            PerilRegions(peril, region, Resolutions(script_data.subregion_resolution_data[0], [subregion]),
                         script_data.subperils, script_data.lobs)])
        return h.json()
    else:
        print("Nothing happened")
```

Comment: maybe you need to apply other logic to your code but for the code as it is you could set an additional `variable=value` when `h` has been set and check for this value when running it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `h` is not None, `merge_to_hierarchy` simply prints "nothing happened"; this means it returns None. Since you are setting `h` in the calling code to the result of that function, this means that the function has the effect of always setting h to None if it is not already None.

You should always return the value of `h` from that function.